# Is $\lim_{x\to \infty} -\frac{2}{\sqrt{x-2} +\sqrt{2}} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was solving following limit problem:

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x})$$

Since (If I get this correctly) $\infty - \infty$ tells us nothing about the solution of the limit problem, we need do something.

After multiplying $(\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x})$ by $\frac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}$, I got:

$$\frac{x-2 - x}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}  =\frac{-2 }{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}} $$

I suppose that if it was something like this $\frac{-2}{\sqrt{x}}$, it would evalute to zero, but what about fractional function like the one above?

---

And while I am at it, I will ask one more question:

suppose it was $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-2 }{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x}}$ , what would that limit evaluate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the fractional function above also evaluates to $0$ since, for $x \to +\infty$, the denominator of $\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}$ goes to $\infty$ even faster than just $\sqrt{x}$, so the reciprocal goes to $0$ faster as well. In particular,

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{-2}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}} = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As for your second question, after rationalizing $\frac{-2 }{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x}}$ by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}$, you get $\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}$, so the answer by [Mishikumo2019](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631353/mishikumo2019) gives the limit in that case is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

You have : $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}=+\infty, $$so the limit of your expression is $0$.

Comment: +1 You could even add the answer of the second part from this.

Comment: You have to apply the same method : $$\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{x-2-x}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}, $$ and the limit is zero.

Comment: Zero, as stated in the last line@Nelver